# Deskjet 2540 wireless connection Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, printing, printer

I'm testing the following printer HP Deskjet 2540 which has wireless capabilities. I have connected it and install it no issues via USB using the hplip which is a brilliant bit of software for Linux printing.

But I simply can not connect it via wireless because unlike all the other HP printers this printer doesn't have an LCD display to which you put your wifi config details into. The manual found here:

```
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/601209/Hp-Deskjet-2540.html
```

Is not helpful what so ever in using Linux, the only advice it offers for setting up the wifi is to either use the CD (doesn't support Linux) or the following:

```
1. Depending on your operating system, do one of the following:
● Windows 8: On the Start screen, right-click an empty area on the screen, click All Apps on
the app bar.
● Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP: From the computer desktop, click Start,
select All Programs, click HP, click HP Deskjet 2540 series.
2. Click Printer Setup & Software.
3. Select Convert a USB connected printer to wireless. Follow the on-screen instructions.
```

What is the Linux equivalent to this?

Answer (score 5):

I just set up this printer by doing the following:

1. Turn the printer off
2. Turn the printer on
3. Hold the red X and the wifi button until the power button flashes
4. Connect to a wifi network with SSID of "HP-Setup-XX-Deskjet 2540 series" (this took a few attempts for some reason)
5. Open up a browser to 192.168.223.1
6. Use the wireless setup wizard to connect to your real network

You can then disconnect and use your printer!

Answer (score 1):

This wrecked my head. I connected to WiFi printer 2 years ago and in the meantime I forgot how to do it again. So after a while I figured it out, and said I'd write it down so I don't forget again!

Here ya go, these are the instructions for Ubuntu obviously!

1. Click on the Wifi icon at top of screen. In options, select “Create New WiFi Network”.
2. A Dialogue box appears.
3. For connection, select “New”
4. For Network Name, put in “HP-Setup-XX-Deskjet 2540 series”
5. For Wi-Fi security, select “None”
6. Go to “search your computer” icon and type in “Printers”
7. Click “Add Printer”
8. Select “Network Printer”
9. A list will appear. Select “HP Deskjet 2540 (HP3CA82A9.......)
10. Press “Forward”
11. Under Connections, choose “HP Linux Imaging and Printing (HPLIP)
12. Select “Forward”
13. It will search for drivers and you can give the printer a name and location.
14. Click “Apply”
15. It will ask you if you want to print a test page.

It should work hopefully!

Answer (score 1):

Install on Solus:

1. Turn on the printer
2. Go to applications (function key)
3. Search for Printers
4. Open Printers
5. HP 2540 will appearon the list
6. Click add
7. Done

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to myself as I keep forgetting how I did it last time and always find this answer which works but is a bit complicated and nowadays there's an easier way of doing so.

If hplip is installed, just run hp-setup and follow instructions on the screen.

hplip-3.17.10 version tested.